# Highlighting cursor or changing cursor size temporarily with keyboard shortcut

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, cursor

My machine has two large screens, and I often find myself editing high-res pictures with a tiny cross-hair cursor that allows me to easily see the image content around the pixel I am editing.

However, sometimes I need to **quickly know where my cursor is**, and because my cursor is so small, just moving the cursor is not enough for me to find it on my screen.

I would love to have a keyboard shortcut that **highlights or changes the cursor size** **temporarily** so that I can quickly see where my cursor is on the screen.

I'm mostly interested in solutions for Windows 7.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check the Mouse Properties in the Windows Control Panel:

[image]

The "Show location of pointer when I press the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key" is functionality Windows has had built in for some considerable time now.

Turn that on, press "Apply", and then tap the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key and you will immediately know where your cursor is.